# Конструкторы Java (Модификатор доступа)

Tags: java, классы

Я еще совсем зеленый в Java. Вопрос: какой модификатор доступа имеет конструктор класса, если не указать его. По сравнению с C#, этот конструктор будет private и я не смогу создать экземпляр класса.

```
Person(){}
```

Как на счет этого в Java? В IntelliJ все нормально билдится
Надеюсь вопрос понятен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию будет **package-private** модификатор.
Т.е. означает, что класс/метод/переменная будут доступны только в пакете (не в родительском и не дочернем, а только в текущем).

Comment: Но при этом я же могу создавать экземпляры класса, не смотря на то, что он private

Comment: @Mii, да, вы можете создать экземпляры класса, но только в текущем пакете. И он не private, а package-private - это разные вещи.

Comment: Я так понимаю вы говорите про 4 тип: 

public: 

private: 

protected: 

Модификатор по умолчанию: Отсутствие модификатора у поля или метода класса предполагает применение к нему модификатора по умолчанию. Такие поля или методы видны всем классам в текущем пакете.

Comment: @Mii верно. Как его только не называют, и package-visible, и private-protected и т.п. Смысл тот же. ))

Comment: Спасибо за просвещение!